# Create donation product with Commerce Kickstart

Tags: commerce

I've installed a fresh copy of [Commerce Kickstart 2](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart) and then installed [Commerce Donate](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_donate).

After the installation, step 1 of the Commerce Donate readme says:

- Create a donation product at Administration » Store » Products

I go `/node/add/add-product` and choose the type Donation. When creating the product there is a select field called product with no options.

It seems like I'm creating the display node not the actual product.

How do I create the actual product?

EDIT: Just found the same question on the Commerce Donate issue queue: [Problem Creating Donation Product](https://www.drupal.org/node/2375497).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone replied on the [Commerce Donate issue thread](https://www.drupal.org/node/2375497#comment-9702569) with a solution.

The solution is to manually go to: `/admin/commerce/products/add/donation` where you can then make your product.